# Cannot execute jar file from aplication that uses XSteam

Tags: java, deployment, xstream, outputstream, jdeveloper

I'm testing to use persisting data using XStream and it works fine when I run it from JDeveloper, BUT when I deploy the app it just simply doesn´texecute.

The frame is simple, a button and a textfield, supposed to create a file with the object inside all in xml code, it works when I run it but not when I deploy it, I include the libraries in the jar file, please help me.

Here the code from the button event:

```
private void jButton1_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
    try {        
        XStream xstream=new XStream(new DomDriver());
        xstream.alias("person", Person.class);
        File file=new File("D:\\out\\personas.xml");
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        OutputStream outputStream= new FileOutputStream(file);      
        ObjectOutputStream out = xstream.createObjectOutputStream(outputStream);            
        out.writeObject(new Person(jTextField1.getText()));
        out.close();
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, jTextField1.getText());            
    } catch (FileNotFoundException f) {
    } catch (IOException f) {
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not wise to catch and discard exceptions. They can tell you all sorts of things.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'deploy' it? Package a jar and trying to execute it with "java -jar ..."? Where do you deploy to?

Comment: Exactly that Timo Hahn.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run the app directly from  a jar if the jar contains other jars. The classloader not look into need jars. 
you run the app from jdev you see the command line. You see that all jars needed add to the class path.